# cannot retrieve indexes correctly mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, fetch

```
$search = htmlspecialchars($_GET["s"]);

if(isset($_GET['s'])) {
// id index exists
$wordarray = explode(" ",$search);
$stringsearch = implode('%',$wordarray);
echo $stringsearch;
echo ",";
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($conn->query("SELECT ID FROM table WHERE title LIKE '%$stringsearch%';")); 
if (!empty($result)) {

 echo sizeof($result);

 echo ",";
```

Database has 3 rows with titles test,pest,nest with corresponding id's 1,2,3. when i request domain.com/?s=est

it echos something like this 
**est,2,**

Now when i checked $result[0] and $result[1], **$result[0]** echoed **1** and **$result[1]** didn't echo anything. When I use foreach function, it is taking only value of $result[0]

and $result should be array of all the three indexes.

I cannot find any mistake,
when i type the same command in sql console it works, somebody help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to sql injection-- and htmlspecialchars is useless here :)

Comment: Now can you explain how to remove sql vulnerability? @Martin

Comment: I would recommend using prepared statements, you can also use mysqli_real_escape_string

Comment: Already did that Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, if you're expecting multiple rows, then don't do this:

```
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($conn->query("SELECT ID FROM table WHERE title LIKE '%$stringsearch%';"));
```

This only fetches the first row, you need to loop it to advance the next pointer and get the next following row set:

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT ID FROM table WHERE title LIKE '%$stringsearch%' ");

while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    echo $row[0] . '<br/>';
    // or $row['ID'];
}
```

Sidenote: Consider using prepared statements instead, since mysqli already supports this.

Comment: Thanx @Ghost, it works if it wasn't for you i would have wasted hours :) ;)

Comment: or mysqli_real_escape_string for now :)